# Why am I getting the access denied errors after login?

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have successfully installed MySQL 5.5.51 in Linux environment and can login db also, but I am unable to do any operation like `select`, `create` and `update`.

Here are the grants of the user;

```
mysql> SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();
+-----------------+----------------+
| USER()          | CURRENT_USER() |
+-----------------+----------------+
| mysql@localhost | @localhost     |
+-----------------+----------------+
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Errors:

```
mysql> create user ravi;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'
mysql> CREATE USER 'ravi'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'sql123';
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Please help me to resolve on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user only have USAGE privilege,which is not enough for executing these operations. If this is a development instance,you can proceed to grant ALL privileges to that user across all databases.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ravi'@'localhost';
```

You need to run this as a privileged user (root or other with enough privileges).

Comment: Hi Manuek, thanks for your replay.. i have tried your suggestion but its not working.. i have logged mysql as below..                            root@localhost bin]# ./mysql -umysql                                                                                                            
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();
+--------------------------------------+
| Grants for @localhost                |
+--------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ''@'localhost' |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: then i have tried your suggestion as below                                          mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysql'@'localhost'
    -> ;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER();                        Please help me

Comment: You need to login as root (mysql -uroot) for applying the GRANT bellow. @ravi

Comment: thanks, for root am facing below issue.                             .[root@localhost bin]# ./mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: `mysql -uroot -p` and put the root password. @ravi

Comment: thanks, facing following issue,                                           [root@localhost bin]# ./mysql -u root -plinux
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: You will need to reset the root password (check skip-grant-tables)

Comment: thanks, do you mean need to change the root user password in Linux environment..? if it is, could you please provide me the steps or command..

Comment: Check this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html). @ravi